# Error when trying to add a column to the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to add a column to my MySQL table like this:

```
$this->dbforge->add_column($receiver_table, $sender_row);
```

What I get is this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 2
>
> ALTER TABLE `C_Ort` ADD Strasse

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what is the value of `$sender_row`

Comment: @ShaifulIslam the value of it is Strasse

Comment: I think you wrote it wrong.add your php code how you assigned it

Comment: Why do you want a function to add a new column? Sound like bad database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $sender_row = array(
                    'Strasse' => array('type' => 'TEXT')//add your type.I think you missed it
 );
 $this->dbforge->add_column($receiver_table, $sender_row);
```

If your field type is different look at the [doc](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html#add_field) how you need to do that

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `add_column` should be an array in the following format:

```
$sender_row = array(
    'Strasse' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '100'
    ),
);
```

See the docs for more details:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/forge.html#adding-fields